# Кнопка на PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, phpmyadmin

Как можно сделать кнопку на PHP которая при нажатии будет зеленого цвета ,а при повторном нажатии серого и + AJAX (подключить ее к серверу) Записывать 1 или 0 в столбец 'work' именно для первого ID  не для второго или третьего ,а для первого .

ДБ

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost"; // название/путь сервера
$username = "root"; // имя пользователя 
$password = "a-1800"; // пароль пользователя 
$dbName = "new_tech_user"; // название базы данных
/* Создаем соединение */
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbName );
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error("Подключиться к серверу не удалось:(");
    exit();
} 
$id ='';
$name = '';
$day = '';
$pass  = '';
$log_ip  = '';
$sort  = '';
$work  = '';
$login  = '';
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tab_1"); // название нашей таблицы "tab_1"
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row['id'];   /* пример вывода записи в теге <button> <?php echo $id; ?></button>*/
    $name   = $row['name'];
    $day      =  $row['day'];
    $pass     =  $row['pass'];
    $log_ip   =  $row['log_ip'];
    $sort     =  $row['sort'];
    $work     =  $row['work'];
    $login    =  $row['login'];
}

?>
```

По такому принципу как на JS только на PHP + можно было на AJAX отправлять запрос и получать с SQL.

```js
        let result = 0;
let myEvent = function() {
  if (result == 0) {
    document.getElementById('my-button').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    result++;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('my-button').style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    result--;
  }
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, false); //url по которому будет выполнятся запрос
  let body = 'result=' + result;
  xhr.send(body);
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  } else {
    alert('При отправке данных произошла ошибка');
  }
}
```

```css
 #my-button {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <button id="my-button" onclick="myEvent()">В РАБОТЕ</button>
<div id="result">0</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у вас собственно все так и работает, при клике на кнопку "В РАБОТЕ" в вас отправляется  ajax запрос на сервер (php) там делайте то что вам надо и отдавайте ответ

Comment: Сейчас немного уточню и подправлю . Просто я думал там нужно как-то по другому сделать только не знаю как ( Мне нужно просто чтоб записывалось именно для первого ID в строку 'work'  не во второй или третий ID  а именно в первый.А с этим кодом почему-то не получается (

Comment: ВОТ  КАК-ТО ТАК .Есть сам файл  connect.php  но по нажатию не могу записать 1 или при повторном нажатии 0 (((

Comment: Вы уже, как минимум, месяц мучаетесь со своей задачей. За это время лучше бы почитали статью (вам скидывали) и у вас бы все получилось! А так задавать вопросы здесь - никто помогать не будет, потому что у вас нету базового понимания.

Comment: Степан ,начнем с того что я на прошлой неделе похожий вопрос задавал ,а во вторых я думаю найдутся добрые люди которые помогут начинающему студенту-программисту .

Comment: я собственно все ровно не могу понять что вы хотите сделать, если вы хотите запретить повторное нажатие кнопки, то после того как вам прийдет верный ответ с сервера   if (xhr.status == 200) то меняйте в кнопке атрибут disabled в true и все

Comment: Вот ,еще раз сбрасываю что нужно .Записывать 1 или 0 в столбец 'work' именно для первого ID не для второго или третьего . Запрос делаю через AJAX

Comment: напишите правильно ли я вас понимаю

1) вывести данные из таблицы, для каждой строки показать кнопку процесса ("добавить в работу", "в обработке") 
2) при нажатии на кнопку делать ajax запрос на сервер и менять поле "work" после чего менять цвет этой кнопки

Comment: Почти.1) При нажатии на кнопку записывается в таблицу work   '1' и цвет кнопки становится зеленым  2) при  нажатии повторном записывается в таблицу work   '0' и цвет кнопки становится серым . Делается через AJAX запрос индивидуально для каждого id

Comment: потому-что если не уточнить к какому id  будет относиться запись , то будет записывать каждый раз с новой строки ,новым id  для столбца 'work'

Comment: madfan41k отпишитесь пожалуйста